# SpringBoot - RequestMapping get the path as variable?

Tags: java, spring

Small question regarding how to get the Spring request mapping (GET mapping, POST mapping...), the path (route) parameter(s) as variable(s). A bit of background, we currently have a use case where we take a route, compute some information, (the Disaster Recovery URL, the test URL, the most available URL, but the question is not here) and respond back. This is just a partial example to have something a bit more concrete in the question.

Query at http://the-main-host.com/firstRoute
We return http://go-to-region-us-west3.com/firstRoute and maybe minutes later, we return http://go-to-region-eu-central.com/firstRoute , but again, this is not the question.

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/firstRoute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> question(@PathVariable @NotBlank final String id, String url) {
    String theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation = computeExtraInformationForURL(id, url);
    return Mono.just(theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation + id + "/firstRoute");
}
```

With time, we are now at some 300 of those handlers, all with real use cases

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/{id}/twoHundredAndFiveRoute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> question(@PathVariable @NotBlank final String id, String url) {
    String theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation = computeExtraInformationForURL(id, url);
    return Mono.just(theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation + id + "/twoHundredAndFiveRoute");
}

@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/twoHundredSixtySevenRoute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> question(@PathVariable @NotBlank final String id, String url) {
    String theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation = computeExtraInformationForURL(id, url);
    return Mono.just(theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation + id + "/twoHundredSixtySevenRoute");
}
```

We managed to make it more maintainable by using the Spring array of the path annotation. This way of doing is a bit nicer, it brought down our two hundred methods down to a single digit. We would like to keep using this way is possible. However, we lose the information what was the path being invoked.

```
@GetMapping(path = {"/{id}/firstRoute", "/{id}/twoHundredSixtySevenRoute"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> question(@PathVariable @NotBlank final String id, String url) {
        String theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation = computeExtraInformationForURL(id, url);
        return Mono.just(theUrlEnrichedWithOtherInformation + id + getThePathThatWasUsedFromTheArrayPlease());
    }
```

Is it possible to get it back, like in this speculative example?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think I understood you. Due to your @GetMapping has a lot of paths,do you need to get the real path that is being invoked?

Comment: Can't you use requestparam to differentiate the different paths?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do something like path="{path}" and map it to a variable as question(@PathVariable String path)?

Comment: No problem @DoNhuVy, thank for the edit

Comment: @JRichardsz nicely said

Comment: @TahirHussainMir that is exactly the question. I would like to avoid such as I have 300 of those

Comment: @SledgeHammer do you have a working example?

Comment: @PatPatPat its in the comment. set your path to "{path}" and your method would be Mono<String> question(@PathVariable String path)

Comment: I see. yes, agreed. However, in my case, I cannot just forward the entire path, since each path has its own logic. Doing as you said, I will then in the method need to perform some kind of if (path.equals"firstRoute") then ... if path.equals("twoHundredSixtySevenRoute") then... which pretty much comes back to having the 300 methods we have now instead of using the array

Comment: Also, the routes in the arrays are actually containing an id /firstRoute/{id} /twoHundredSixtySevenRoute{id} already (question updated)

Comment: then you would just have 2 path variables: "{path}/{id}" and 2 @PathVariables. You haven't clearly stated why you have 300 endpoints, that doesn't make any sense. There's no common logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to access the **HttpServletRequest** instance. This has a lot of information about http invocation.

Spring allow us an easy way to access to this instance:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/{objectId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void generateReport(
        @PathVariable("objectId") Long objectId, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {

}
```

If you have access to **HttpServletRequest**, you can get any part of the url:

Example: http://myhost:8080/people?lastname=Fox&age=30

```
String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +   // "http" + "://
             request.getServerName() +       // "myhost"
             ":" +                           // ":"
             request.getServerPort() +       // "8080"
             request.getRequestURI() +       // "/people"
             "?" +                           // "?"
             request.getQueryString();       // "lastname=Fox&age=30"
```

**request.getRequestURI()** should have the path value that you need.

Comment: I was sure there were a smart way to do it that I didn't knew. That's much better than what I have now. Thanks. However, I am in a reactive world, so it is not a straightforward for HttpServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from `HttpServletRequest` - `request.getRequestURI()`. Either autowire it or use it from method parameter.